# What does it mean when a generic type is bounded by a generic lifetime?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm studying lifetimes in Rust. A lifetime is denoted by `'a`, and can be used like this:

```rust
fn function1<'a>(param1: &'a str) -> &'a str
```

However I found this piece of code:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a> RingBuffer<'a, T> {
```

It makes no sense for me for `T` to be of type `'a`. Types and lifetimes aren't the same thing for me. What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a generic type parameter followed by a colon and a lifetime, it means that a lifetime bound is placed on the type.

For example, in the case you have quoted:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> RingBuffer<'a, T> {
```

the type `T` must live at least as long as the lifetime `'a` (note that the compiler does not know what T is - T may itself contain references or contain other types which contain references).

Looking more closely at the [implementation of RingBuffer](https://docs.rs/smoltcp/0.5.0/src/smoltcp/storage/ring_buffer.rs.html#25-29) (which I assume you found in the smoltcp crate), you can see the reason: the `RingBuffer` may contain a reference to a borrowed buffer (via [ManagedSlice](https://docs.rs/managed/0.3.0/managed/enum.ManagedSlice.html)). This makes sense: if you create a `RingBuffer` using perhaps a stack allocated buffer, the buffer must last at least as long as the `RingBuffer`.

There is a section titled "[Advanced Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.28.0/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html)" in an older version of "the book". I could not find it in the newer editions, but I found it useful in understanding this. You might also want to refer to the rust reference section "[Trait and lifetime bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html)"

Answer (score 2):

`T: 'a` is a lifetime bound on `T`. From the [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds):

> `T: 'a` means that all lifetime parameters of `T` outlive '`a`. For example
>   if `'a` is an unconstrained lifetime parameter then `i32: 'static` and
>   `&'static str: 'a` are satisfied but `Vec<&'a ()>: 'static` is not.

In the specific piece of code you give, the lifetime bound `T: 'a` is saying that the things you put in the ring buffer must have lifetimes at least as long as the lifetime of the `RingBuffer`.

Comment: `Vec<&'a ()>: 'static` cannot be put into a reference `let x: &'static Vec<something>` because the insides of `Vec<&'a ()>` have lifetime less than `static`? Can you give an example? I don't know what to put in `something`

Answer (score 1):

`T: 'a` should be read as *"`T` is bounded by `'a`"* not *"`T` has a lifetime of `'a`"*.

Also, `T` includes *all possible types*, including reference types which have lifetimes. `&str`, `&i32`, etc are all valid types in `T`. Furthermore, to use a simplified version of your example, you can have an owned type which is generic over lifetimes, because it contains a reference type, like so:

```rust
struct Ref<'a, T: 'a>(&'a T);
```

The struct is generic over `'a` and `T` because it can hold `&'a T` references.

One more point: `&'a T` requires `T: 'a` because for `T` to be valid for `'a` it must outlive `'a`. For example, construction of this type would be rejected by the compiler `&'static Ref<'a, i32>` because if `Ref` is only valid for `'a` we can't take a `'static` reference to it.